# How to draw an ellipse around polygon?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-10.4, ellipse

[image]I am trying to ellipses around polygons I have in im map, in ArcGIS 10.4. This what I need in the further steps for displacement of polygons. These polygons are from a geologic map and these specific polygons are small ones which I need to displace by drawing ellipse around them. One may ask, why not circle? Well, there are very different shapes in the map such as very round, very narrow and long, short, thus ellipse would fit them well than circle.

Update:

I could use two ways to find centroid, first, from feature to point (with inside) and second, centroid from "Calculate Geometry".

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the polygons?

Comment: A circle is an ellipse, with co-located loci. There are many ways to generate ellipses in ArcGIS, all of them well-documented.  What have you tried? If using ArcPy, please provide your code. Please also [Edit] the question to include how you are going to locate the center point, semi-major and semi-minor axis, and orientation.

Comment: Have you tried the buffer tool and if so, please describe why it does not fit your use-case.

Comment: I am not quite sure how can I use buffer for this. The idea is, if the polygon is inside the circle the may be several instances it could be moved. This instances could be 4, 8, 12 and so on. And putting the circle with polygon inside would displace them and remove the conflict between other polygons. But for elongated polygons it would have large deviation from original space and cause large topology error. There, I am trying ellipse instead of circle.